# How to deserialize xml with a polymorphic root element?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, polymorphism

Given the classes:

`class Base { }
class Derived : Base { public string Value { get; set; } }`

With this XML:
`<Derived><Value>something</Value></Derived>`

Is there a way to create a serializer that can deserialize this only knowing the base class:

`var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
var b = (Base)serializer.Deserialize(stream);`

I know how to deal with polymorphic sub elements but not the root element its self.

I feel like this question must have been asked before but I'm not finding the answer so a link to an answer would more than enough :)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086893/how-to-do-a-polymorphic-deserialization-in-c-sharp-given-a-xsd

Comment: Just want to add that I have no control over the xml format, this is being used to parse an xml messaging protocol and message type must be identified by the root element name.

Comment: @JohnB Yes, that would work and it may be my only option but I was hoping not to have to parse the xml twice. Seems like a waste to parse the XML once to get the root element name, map that to a serializer and then reparse the xlm again to deserialize into an object.