# XML deserialization of different classes in file

Tags: c#, xml

I get a file with different content (currently 4 different classes), either

```
<ClassA><!-- content --></ClassA>
```

or

```
<ClassB><!-- content --></ClassB>
```

or ...

At time of parsing I have no further information which class is in the file.

So, currently, I try to parse by trial and error:

```
try
{
  ClassA result = (ClassA)new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA)).Deserialize(reader);
  if(!(result is null)) { \\do something }
}
catch (Exception) {}
```

And the same for `ClassB` and so on ...

Is there a more elegant way to parse the classes?

I can give all classes the same base class, although the are quite different in their form.

Comment: Brute force?  Read the first line and look for the appropriate name? It's kludge and horribly inelegant, but it might solve your problem

Comment: Inherit your classes from a common ancestor. Use the XmlIncludeAttribute.

Comment: You could use `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)` to check to see whether a given serializer is able to deserialize a given root element.  See [How to deserialize XML if the return type could be an Error or Success object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44234061/3744182).

Comment: And additional options to be found at [How to do a polymorphic deserialization in C# given a XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28086893/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with `XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize(XmlReader)`

```
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                    if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
                    {
                        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
                }
                throw new XmlException("Invalid xml type");
            }
```