# C# XML serialization override Type of IXmlSerializable Class

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, ixmlserializable

## Initial question

I want to `serialize` a `List<IXmlSerializable>` changing the **XmlType** of the `IXmlSerializable` class dynamically (so I can't use attributes tags to do that)

I' ve tried to use **XmlAttributeOverrides** to do that with no success so far.

Here is a sample code illustrating the issue :
**IXmlSerializable class (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx)) :**

```
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    // Private state
    private string personName;


    // Constructors
    public Person(string name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public Person()
    {
        personName = null;
    }


    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(personName);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        personName = reader.ReadString();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }


    // Print
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (personName);
    }
}
```

**Test class (using console for output) :**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> lPersonList = new List<Person> {
            new Person("First"),
            new Person("Second"),
            new Person("Third")
        };
        XmlAttributeOverrides lOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes lAttributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlType = new XmlTypeAttribute("Employee") };
        lOverrides.Add(typeof(Person), lAttributes);

        XmlSerializer lSerialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>), lOverrides, null, new XmlRootAttribute("Employees"), null);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces lNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        lNamespaces.Add("", "");
        lSerialiser.Serialize(Console.Out, lPersonList, lNamespaces);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Enter any key to close.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here is what I want to get :

```
<Employees>
<Employee>First</Employee>
<Employee>Second</Employee>
<Employee>Third</Employee>
</Employees>
```

But I get this error on runtime :

> System.InvalidOperationException: Only XmlRoot attribute may be specified for the type Person. Please use XmlSchemaProviderAttribute to specify schema type.

**Note**  When my **Person class** is not implementing `IXmlSerializable`, everything works well...

Could someone help me on that ?

---

## **Choosen solution (based on [@dbc answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38158389/6284691%20%22@dbc%20answer%22)))**

As @dbc pointed out, using a "surrogate" class is the easiest way of doing what I want. But as I've said, I need to change the Person type dynamically, which means that I can't use attributes tags.
So I still use `XmlAttributeOverrides` in my final design, here it is :

**Surrogate `List<Person>` Class** (same as @dbc without attributes tags) :

```
public class EmployeesListSurrogate
{
    public List<Person> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator List<Person>(EmployeesListSurrogate surrogate)
    {
        return surrogate == null ? null : surrogate.EmployeeList;
    }

    public static implicit operator EmployeesListSurrogate(List<Person> employees)
    {
        return new EmployeesListSurrogate { EmployeeList = employees };
    }
}
```

**Test class using surrogate :**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> lPersonList = new List<Person> {
            new Person("First"),
            new Person("Second"),
            new Person("Third")
        };

        XmlAttributeOverrides lOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes lEmployeesListAttributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("Employees") };
        lOverrides.Add(typeof(EmployeesListSurrogate), lEmployeesListAttributes);
        XmlAttributes lEmployeeAttributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlElements = { new XmlElementAttribute("Employee") } };
        lOverrides.Add(typeof(EmployeesListSurrogate), "EmployeeList", lEmployeeAttributes);

        XmlSerializer lSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EmployeesListSurrogate), lOverrides);
        XmlSerializerNamespaces lNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        lNamespaces.Add("", "");
        lSerializer.Serialize(Console.Out, (EmployeesListSurrogate)lPersonList, lNamespaces);
    }
}
```

I want to end this with a big thanks to @dbc, your answer was very helpfull and informative, I've learned a lot. I can't upvote you but I hope the community will do !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to get the XML you desire would be to serialize a "surrogate" class as follows:

```
[XmlRoot("Employees")]
public class EmployeesListSurrogate
{
    [XmlElement("Employee")]
    public List<Person> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator List<Person>(EmployeesListSurrogate surrogate)
    {
        return surrogate == null ? null : surrogate.EmployeeList;
    }

    public static implicit operator EmployeesListSurrogate(List<Person> employees)
    {
        return new EmployeesListSurrogate { EmployeeList = employees };
    }
}
```

This completely eliminates the need for `XmlAttributeOverrides`.  Or you can use `XmlAttributeOverrides` along with [`XmlAttributes.XmlElements`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlelements.aspx) to specify the XML name for `EmployeeList` dynamically.

That being said, the reason the `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when you try to apply `[XmlType]` to a type that also implements `IXmlSerializable` is that `XmlSerializer` requires the type name to be returned via an entirely different mechanism, namely the [`XmlSchemaProviderAttribute.MethodName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaproviderattribute.methodname.aspx) method specified in an [`[XmlSchemaProvider]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaproviderattribute.aspx) attribute.

When `[XmlSchemaProvider]` is applied to an `IXmlSerializable` type, `XmlSerializer` will look for a public static method of the type whose name is specified in the attribute constructor and has the following signature:

```
    public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchemaMethod(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
    }
```

The purpose of this method is twofold:

1. It should fill in the `XmlSchemaSet` with the expected schema when serializing instances of the type.  By testing, I found that it has to be filled with *something valid*.  It cannot just be left empty, or an exception will be thrown.

   (I don't know to what extent `XmlSerializer` actually validates against the schema when serializing.  The method also gets invoked when exporting schema information via `xsd.exe`.)
2. It should return the XML type name for the type.

   This seems to be why Microsoft throws the exception you are seeing: since the schema attribute provider should return the type name, an `XmlType` attribute would be in conflict.

Thus if I modify your `Person` class as follows:

```
[XmlSchemaProvider("GetSchemaMethod")]
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    // Private state
    private string personName;

    // Constructors
    public Person(string name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public Person()
    {
        personName = null;
    }

    // This is the method named by the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute applied to the type.
    public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchemaMethod(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
        string EmployeeSchema = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault=""qualified"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
  <xs:import namespace=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" />
  <xs:element name=""Employee"" nillable=""true"" type=""Employee"" />
  <xs:complexType name=""Employee"" mixed=""true"">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:any />
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>";

        using (var textReader = new StringReader(EmployeeSchema))
        using (var schemaSetReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            xs.Add("", schemaSetReader);
        }
        return new XmlQualifiedName("Employee");
    }

    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(personName);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        var isEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            personName = reader.ReadContentAsString();
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }

    // Print
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (personName);
    }
}
```

And serialize your `List<Person>` to XML, I get the following result:

```
<ArrayOfEmployee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Employee>First</Employee>
    <Employee>Second</Employee>
    <Employee>Third</Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>
```

As you can see, the XML type name for `Person` has been successfully specified.

However, you want to *dynamically override* the XML type name for `Person` via `XmlAttributeOverrides` rather than set it at compile type.  To do this, it would seem necessary to specify a `XmlSchemaProviderAttribute` inside [`XmlAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.aspx).  Unfortunately, **there is no `XmlSchemaProvider` property to be found inside `XmlAttributes`.**  It appears Microsoft never implemented such functionality.  Thus, if you want to pursue this design further, you're going to need to do something kludgy: temporarily override the return of `GetSchemaMethod()` when creating the override serializer.  Two things to keep in mind:

1. Under the hood, `XmlSerializer` works by creating a dynamic assembly.  If you construct an `XmlSerializer` with `new XmlSerializer(Type)` or `new XmlSerializer(Type, String)`, then .Net will cache the assembly and reuse it when a serializer is constructed a second time.

   Thus, attempting to temporarily override the return of `GetSchemaMethod()` when constructing a serializer using either of these will fail or produce unexpected results.
2. Otherwise the dynamic assemblies are *not* cached and so your code *must* cache the serializer manually or have a severe resource leak.  See [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer).

   In these cases temporarily overriding the return of `GetSchemaMethod()` could work.

All this being said, the following produces the XML you require:

```
[XmlSchemaProvider("GetSchemaMethod")]
public class Person : IXmlSerializable
{
    // Private state
    private string personName;

    // Constructors
    public Person(string name)
    {
        personName = name;
    }

    public Person()
    {
        personName = null;
    }

    [ThreadStatic]
    static string personXmlTypeName;

    const string defaultXmlTypeName = "Person";

    static string PersonXmlTypeName
    {
        get
        {
            if (personXmlTypeName == null)
                personXmlTypeName = defaultXmlTypeName;
            return personXmlTypeName;
        }
        set
        {
            personXmlTypeName = value;
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable PushXmlTypeName(string xmlTypeName)
    {
        return new PushValue<string>(xmlTypeName, () => PersonXmlTypeName, val => PersonXmlTypeName = val);
    }

    // This is the method named by the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute applied to the type.
    public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchemaMethod(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
        string EmployeeSchemaFormat = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
            <xs:schema elementFormDefault=""qualified"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
              <xs:import namespace=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" />
              <xs:element name=""{0}"" nillable=""true"" type=""{0}"" />
              <xs:complexType name=""{0}"" mixed=""true"">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any />
              </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:schema>";
        var EmployeeSchema = string.Format(EmployeeSchemaFormat, PersonXmlTypeName);

        using (var textReader = new StringReader(EmployeeSchema))
        using (var schemaSetReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            xs.Add("", schemaSetReader);
        }
        return new XmlQualifiedName(PersonXmlTypeName);
    }

    // Xml Serialization Infrastructure
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(personName);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        var isEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        if (!isEmpty)
        {
            personName = reader.ReadContentAsString();
            reader.ReadEndElement();
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }

    // Print
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (personName);
    }
}

public struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            setValue(oldValue);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class PersonEmployeeListSerializerFactory
{
    static Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, XmlSerializer> serializers;
    static object padlock = new object();

    static PersonEmployeeListSerializerFactory()
    {
        serializers = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer GetSerializer(string rootName, string personName)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            var key = Tuple.Create(rootName, personName);
            if (!serializers.TryGetValue(key, out serializer))
            {
                using (Person.PushXmlTypeName(personName))
                {
                    var lOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
                    //var lAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
                    //lOverrides.Add(typeof(Person), lAttributes);

                    serializers[key] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>), lOverrides, new Type[0], new XmlRootAttribute(rootName), null);
                }
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

Then do

```
var lSerialiser = PersonEmployeeListSerializerFactory.GetSerializer("Employees", "Employee");

var lNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
lNamespaces.Add("", "");

var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    lSerialiser.Serialize(writer, lPersonList, lNamespaces);

Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

But as you can see this is much more complicated than using the surrogate shown initially.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uMYUOB) showing both options.