# Using XmlAttributeOverrides to ignore elements not working

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm doing the following to ignore a couple of elements on serialization only:

```
public class Parent
{
    public SomeClass MyProperty {get;set;}
    public List<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public SomeClass MyProperty {get;set;}
}

public class SomeClass 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

XmlAttributes ignore = new XmlAttributes()
{
    XmlIgnore = true
};

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(SomeClass), "MyProperty", ignore);

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyParent), overrides);
```

The class properties do not have the `XmlElement` attribute. The property name also matches the string passed to `overrides.Add`.

However, the above is not ignoring the property and it's still serialized.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the code example is `MyParent` supposed to be `Parent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type to pass in to [`XmlAttributeOverrides.Add(Type type, string member, XmlAttributes attributes)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c5dw5z7(v=vs.110).aspx) is not the type that the member returns.  It's the type in which the member is *declared*.  Thus to ignore `MyProperty` in both `Parent` and `Child` you must do:

```
XmlAttributes ignore = new XmlAttributes()
{
    XmlIgnore = true
};

XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
//overrides.Add(typeof(SomeClass), "MyProperty", ignore); // Does not work.  MyProperty is not a member of SomeClass
overrides.Add(typeof(Parent), "MyProperty", ignore);
overrides.Add(typeof(Child), "MyProperty", ignore);

xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent), overrides);
```

Note that, if you construct an `XmlSerializer` with overrides, you must cache it statically to avoid a severe memory leak.  See [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182) for details.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rctSMe).

Comment: After many days of fighting the serializer, I found out there was a bug that did the same thing with derived classes. If a property is inherited, it is not enough to override the attribute of the property in the class being serialized. You must override the property in its _base_ class to make the serializer recognize the new attribute, mangling the normal advantages of subclassing.