# Constructor of a XmlSerializer serializing a List<T> throws an InvalidOperationException when used with XmlAttributeOverrides

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

**Summary**

When using the `XmlSerializer` class, serializing a `List<T>` (where T can be serialized with `XmlSerializer` without problems) using `XmlAttributeOverrides` such as this:

```
using xmls = System.Xml.Serialization;
...
            xmls.XmlAttributeOverrides attributeOverrides = new xmls.XmlAttributeOverrides();
            attributeOverrides.Add(typeof(T), new xmls.XmlAttributes()
            {
                XmlRoot = new xmls.XmlRootAttribute("foo")
            });
            attributeOverrides.Add(typeof(List<T>), new xmls.XmlAttributes()
            {                    
                XmlArray = new xmls.XmlArrayAttribute("foobar"),
                XmlArrayItems = { new xmls.XmlArrayItemAttribute("foo") },                    
            });
```

will throw the following InvalidOperationExcpetion at the inner-most exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may not be specified for the type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[T, programname, Version=versionnumber, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
```

---

**What I expect from the serializer**

```
<texparams>
    <texparam pname="TextureMinFilter" value="9729"/>
    <texparam pname="TextureMagFilter" value="9729"/>
</texparams>
```

**What I can sucessfully get at the moment**

```
<ArrayOfTextureParameter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TextureParameter pname="TextureMinFilter" value="9729" />
    <TextureParameter pname="TextureMagFilter" value="9728" />
</ArrayOfTextureParameter>
```

---

**Background Info**

I have been messing around with XML Serialization lately but have come across a problem. I am trying to serialize and deserialize some classes that wrap OpenGL textures.

In one of my classes (which I appropriately called `BitmapTexture2d`) I have a `Bitmap` field, which I wish to store in a Base64 element like so:

```
<bitmap64>
    *base64goeshere*
</bitmap64>
```

Since I want to keep my code as neat as possible I decided to use the `IXmlSerializable` interface instead of creating a property which  can convert a `string` and a `Bitmap` back and forth.

Later on in the process I decided to use the `XmlSerializer` class to generate the XML for a single field defined in `Texture2d` (which `BitmapTexture2d` is derived from) called `Parameters` (which is a `List<TextureParameter>` and `TextureParameter` is serializable by the `XmlSerialization` class). However this is how the serializer defaulted to serializing the `List<TextureParameter>`:

```
<ArrayOfTextureParameter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <TextureParameter pname="TextureMinFilter" value="9729" />
    <TextureParameter pname="TextureMagFilter" value="9728" />
  </ArrayOfTextureParameter>
```

After seeing this, I decided to try and change the names of the nodes. After some research (where I landed at stackoverflow multiple times) I discovered the `XmlAttributeOverrides` class which can be passed to the constructor of `XmlSerializer` to add/override node names etc.

After writing out my code, the constructor for the sub-serializer started throwing an exception as described above. I have tried using an array which threw the same exception. I later though to serialize each element in the list one by one, but came to the conclusion that it was harder than I thought to achieve it that way. I posted this question somewhere else with no answer. And here I am...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use overrides to attach [`[XmlArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`[XmlArrayItem]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.type(v=vs.110).aspx) to the *type `List<T>`*.  However, as shown in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), `[XmlArray]` cannot be used in this manner:

> ```
> [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field 
>                         | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.ReturnValue, 
>     AllowMultiple = false)]
> public class XmlArrayAttribute : Attribute
> ```

Notice there is no [`AttributeTargets.Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets(v=vs.110).aspx) included?  That means that `[XmlArray]` *cannot be applied directly to a type* and so attempting to do so via XML overrides rightly throws an exception.

But as to why that exception message states,

> System.InvalidOperationException: **XmlRoot** and **XmlType** attributes may not be specified for the type System.Collections.Generic.List`1...

Er, well, that message is simply wrong.  It would appear to be a minor bug in `XmlSerializer`.  You could even report it to Microsoft if you want.

What you need to do instead is:

- Override the [`[XmlRoot]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute of `List<T>` to specify the desired name, in this case "texparams", AND
- Override the [`[XmlType]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute of `T` and set [`XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.typename(v=vs.110).aspx) to be the desired collection element name.  In the absence of an `[XmlArrayItem(name)]` override this is what controls the element names of collections whose items are of type `T`.

Thus your code should look like:

```
static XmlSerializer MakeListSerializer<T>(string rootName, string elementName)
{
    xmls.XmlAttributeOverrides attributeOverrides = new xmls.XmlAttributeOverrides();
    attributeOverrides.Add(typeof(List<T>), new xmls.XmlAttributes()
    {
        XmlRoot = new xmls.XmlRootAttribute(rootName),
    });
    attributeOverrides.Add(typeof(T), new xmls.XmlAttributes()
    {
        XmlType = new xmls.XmlTypeAttribute(elementName),
    });

    return new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), attributeOverrides);
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPrBgp).

Note that when constructing an `XmlSerializer` using `XmlAttributeOverrides` you must cache the serializer for later reuse to avoid a severe memory leak, for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182).

Comment: The answer is definitely correct, so I marked it. I found the way it has to be done not intuitive, however makes sense from a programming perspective. Where should I report the bug to, directly Microsoft or the .Net Foundation?

Comment: @utkumaden - *Where should I report the bug to* - honestly I'm not sure any more.  It used to be that `XmlSerializer` bugs could be filed at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio.