# How to solve: "You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the member." when using XmlAttributeOverrides?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm trying to use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to change the way my class is being serialized to XML. I need to exclude some properties and include others in a specific order.

I have this code here:

```
// XML Attribute Overrrides
public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXMLAttributeOverrides(Type theType, List<string> propertiesToInlcudeInOrder, List<string> allColumnNames)
{
    try
    {
        if (propertiesToInlcudeInOrder != null)
        {
            XmlAttributeOverrides theXMLAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            if (propertiesToInlcudeInOrder.Count > 0)
            {
                XmlAttributes mainNewXMLAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
                mainNewXMLAttributes.XmlIgnore = false;

                XmlAttributes ignoreXMLAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
                ignoreXMLAttributes.XmlIgnore = true;

                List<string> propertiesToNotInclude = new List<string>();
                foreach (string theColumnName in allColumnNames)
                {
                    string thePropertyName = theColumnName;
                    bool addProperty = true;
                    foreach (string propertyToInclude in propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)
                    {
                        if (thePropertyName == propertyToInclude)
                        {
                            addProperty = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (addProperty)
                    {
                        propertiesToNotInclude.Add(thePropertyName);
                    }
                }

                // To Ignore
                foreach (string propertyNameToNotInlcude in propertiesToNotInclude)
                {
                    XmlElementAttribute theXMLElementAttributeToAdd = new XmlElementAttribute(propertyNameToNotInlcude);
                    theXMLElementAttributeToAdd.ElementName = propertyNameToNotInlcude;
                    ignoreXMLAttributes.XmlElements.Add(theXMLElementAttributeToAdd);

                    theXMLAttributeOverrides.Add(theType, propertyNameToNotInlcude, ignoreXMLAttributes);
                }

                // To Add In Order
                int counter = 1;
                foreach (string propertyNameToIncludeInOrder in propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)
                {
                    XmlElementAttribute theXMLElementAttributeToAdd = new XmlElementAttribute(propertyNameToIncludeInOrder);
                    theXMLElementAttributeToAdd.ElementName = propertyNameToIncludeInOrder;
                    theXMLElementAttributeToAdd.Order = counter;
                    mainNewXMLAttributes.XmlElements.Add(theXMLElementAttributeToAdd);

                    theXMLAttributeOverrides.Add(theType, propertyNameToIncludeInOrder, mainNewXMLAttributes);

                    counter++;
                }
            }

            return theXMLAttributeOverrides;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error at 'GetXMLAttributeOverrides'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In my test I have a class with 13 properties and I want to include 3 in a specific order and exclude all the others.

I have made sure that I don't have any duplicates in my lists. I have double checked that I don't have the same property name in the 'Ignore List' and the 'Include List'. I get an exception on this line of my code: `XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType(), allXMLAttribueOverrides);`

`allXMLAttribueOverrides` Is returned from my method `GetXMLAttributeOverrides`

The exception is:

> There was an error reflecting type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SystemName.UserControls.TestMain]'.

Inner exception is:

> There was an error reflecting property 'TextColumn'.
>
> You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'TextColumn'
>   member.

'TextColumn' is the first property in my test class

Here's my test code:

```
TestMain testItem = new TestMain(null, "TextColumnTEST", 5, Convert.ToDecimal(0.333), Convert.ToDecimal(0.777), DateTime.Now, "12:00:00", DateTime.Now, true, "Password", "#FFFFFF", null, null, null);
List<TestMain> dataToSerialize = new List<TestMain>();
dataToSerialize.Add(testItem);

List<string> propertiesToInlcudeInOrder = new List<string>();
propertiesToInlcudeInOrder.Add("CurrencyColumn");
propertiesToInlcudeInOrder.Add("NumberColumn");
propertiesToInlcudeInOrder.Add("TextColumn");

List<string> allColumnNames = new List<string>();
allColumnNames.Add("ID");
allColumnNames.Add("Select");
allColumnNames.Add("TextColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("NumberColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("CurrencyColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("DecimalColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("DateColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("TimeColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("DateAndTimeColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("YesNoColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("PasswordColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("ColorColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("ImageColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("DocumentColumn");
allColumnNames.Add("OtherColumn");

XmlAttributeOverrides allXMLAttribueOverrides = ReportingManipulation.GetXMLAttributeOverrides(dataToSerialize[0].GetType(), propertiesToInlcudeInOrder, allColumnNames);

using (StringWriter mainStringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer mainXMLSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType(), allXMLAttribueOverrides);
    mainXMLSerializer.Serialize(mainStringWriter, dataToSerialize);
    return mainStringWriter.ToString();
}
```

and here's my test class:

```
public class TestMain
{
    #region Properties

    // Properties

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Select { get; set; }

    public string TextColumn { get; set; }
    public int NumberColumn { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrencyColumn { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalColumn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateColumn { get; set; }
    public string TimeColumn { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAndTimeColumn { get; set; }
    public bool YesNoColumn { get; set; }
    public string PasswordColumn { get; set; }
    public string ColorColumn { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageColumn { get; set; }
    public byte[] DocumentColumn { get; set; }
    public byte[] OtherColumn { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    // Constructors
    public TestMain()
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error at Constructor: 'TestMain'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
    public TestMain(int? theID, string theTextColumn, int theNumberColumn, decimal theCurrencyColumn, decimal theDecimalColumn, DateTime theDateColumn, string theTimeColumn, DateTime theDateAndTimeColumn, bool theYesNoColumn, string thePasswordColumn, string theColorColumn, byte[] theImageColumn, byte[] theDocumentColumn, byte[] theOtherColumn)
    {
        try
        {
            this.ID = theID;

            this.TextColumn = theTextColumn;
            this.NumberColumn = theNumberColumn;
            this.CurrencyColumn = theCurrencyColumn;
            this.DecimalColumn = theDecimalColumn;
            this.DateColumn = theDateColumn;
            this.TimeColumn = theTimeColumn;
            this.DateAndTimeColumn = theDateAndTimeColumn;
            this.YesNoColumn = theYesNoColumn;
            this.PasswordColumn = thePasswordColumn;
            this.ColorColumn = theColorColumn;
            this.ImageColumn = theImageColumn;
            this.DocumentColumn = theDocumentColumn;
            this.OtherColumn = theOtherColumn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error at Constructor: 'TestMain'" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @dbc :) without the overrides it works fine. I'll edit my question to contain example code.

Comment: I've noticed that if I ignore the `// To Add In Order` loop of my method; then there are no problems. But that way I miss out on the order of the columns that I want serialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your basic problem** is that you are adding multiple override [`[XmlElement]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attributes for each of your properties, because you are using a single instance `mainNewXMLAttributes` for all of them, which accumulates the `XmlElementAttribute` objects defined for all of them.

**To fix this**, you need to allocate a fresh `mainNewXMLAttributes` for each property inside the `foreach (var propertyNameToIncludeInOrder in propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)` loop, as shown in the following corrected and simplified version of `GetXMLAttributeOverrides()`:

```
public static partial class ReportingManipulation
{
    public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXMLAttributeOverrides(Type theType, IList<string> propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)
    {
        var allProperties = theType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => p.Name);
        return GetXMLAttributeOverrides(theType, propertiesToInlcudeInOrder, allProperties);
    }

    // XML Attribute Overrrides
    public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXMLAttributeOverrides(Type theType, IList<string> propertiesToInlcudeInOrder, IEnumerable<string> allProperties)
    {
        if (propertiesToInlcudeInOrder == null || propertiesToInlcudeInOrder.Count == 0)
            return null;

        var theXMLAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        // To Add In Order
        int counter = 1;
        foreach (var propertyNameToIncludeInOrder in propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)
        {
            // Allocate a fresh instance of XmlAttributes for each property, because we are defining a different
            // XmlElementAttribute for each
            var mainNewXMLAttributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = false };

            // Specify the element order XmlElementAttribute and attach to the XmlAttributes
            var theXMLElementAttributeToAdd = new XmlElementAttribute { Order = counter };
            mainNewXMLAttributes.XmlElements.Add(theXMLElementAttributeToAdd);

            // Attach the override XmlElementAttribute to the property propertyNameToIncludeInOrder
            theXMLAttributeOverrides.Add(theType, propertyNameToIncludeInOrder, mainNewXMLAttributes);

            counter++;
        }

        // To Ignore
        // Using System.Linq.Enumerable.Except()
        var propertiesToNotInclude = allProperties.Except(propertiesToInlcudeInOrder);
        var ignoreXMLAttributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
        foreach (var propertyNameToNotInlcude in propertiesToNotInclude)
        {
            // Attach the override XmlElementAttribute to the property propertyNameToIncludeInOrder
            // No need to allocate a fresh instance of ignoreXMLAttributes for each, because the instances would all be identical
            theXMLAttributeOverrides.Add(theType, propertyNameToNotInlcude, ignoreXMLAttributes);
        }

        return theXMLAttributeOverrides;
    }
}
```

**Why does your code not work?**  In your initial code, you do:

```
XmlAttributes mainNewXMLAttributes = new XmlAttributes();
mainNewXMLAttributes.XmlIgnore = false;

int counter = 1;
foreach (string propertyNameToIncludeInOrder in propertiesToInlcudeInOrder)
{
    XmlElementAttribute theXMLElementAttributeToAdd = new XmlElementAttribute(propertyNameToIncludeInOrder);
    theXMLElementAttributeToAdd.ElementName = propertyNameToIncludeInOrder;
    theXMLElementAttributeToAdd.Order = counter;
    mainNewXMLAttributes.XmlElements.Add(theXMLElementAttributeToAdd);

    theXMLAttributeOverrides.Add(theType, propertyNameToIncludeInOrder, mainNewXMLAttributes);

    counter++;
}
```

Now, the method [`XmlAttributeOverrides.Add(Type, String, XmlAttributes)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlAttributeOverrides_Add_System_Type_System_String_System_Xml_Serialization_XmlAttributes_) is documented to work as follows:

> Adds an `XmlAttributes` object to the collection of `XmlAttributes` objects. The `type` parameter specifies an object to be overridden. The `member` parameter specifies the name of a member that is overridden.

Thus the contents of `mainNewXMLAttributes` will get applied to the named parameter when the `XmlSerializer` is eventually constructed.  And as you construct only instance of `mainNewXMLAttributes` for all parameters, its `XmlElements` array will contain element names corresponding to *all* of the parameters!  I.e. you code attempts to apply multiple `[XmlElement]` attributes to each named parameter, differing only in override name and order.  This accounts for the *You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'TextColumn' member.* exception -- you can only attach multiple element names to a property if the property value is polymorphic and you want to assign different element names to different value types.

**Notes**

- When generating an `XmlSerializer` with overrides, you must cache it statically and reuse it later to avoid a severe memory leak, as explained in *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182)*.
- I don't recommend unconditionally swallowing exceptions and presenting them as error messages to the user in low-level utility methods or object constructors.

**Demo working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SJoDx3).**

Comment: Works perfectly :D. Thanks for your help and advice. I appreciate it.