# XmlSerializer: deserialize recursive object graph

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Given the following XML I want to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<units>      
  <entity>
    <health max="1000"/>   
    <sprite texture="tank"/>
    <entity>        
      <sprite texture="tank-turret"/> <!-- this element is missing when i deserialize --!>
    </entity>    
  </entity>         
</units>
```

How can I deserialize this recursive object graph using `XmlSerializer`?

The following is my last try. It successfully deserializes the top-level objects (health, sprite, entity) but it does not seem to find the sprite element in the nested entity node.
I also tried deriving entity from componentlist, but it didn't work either.

```
public class UnitSerializer
{
    public abstract class item
    {
    }

    public class entity : item
    {
        [XmlArray("entity")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(health))]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(entity))]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(sprite))]
        public componentlist entity2 { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class component : item
    {
    }

    public class health : component
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int max { get; set; }
    }

    public class sprite : component
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string texture { get; set; }

    }

    public class componentlist : List<item>
    {
    }

    [XmlRoot("units")]
    public class units
    {
        [XmlArray("entity")]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(health))]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(entity))]
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(sprite))]
        public componentlist entity { get; set; }
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(units),
            new[] {
                        typeof(componentlist),
                        typeof(entity),
                        typeof(health),
                        typeof(sprite)
                });
        var fs = new FileStream("units.xml", FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
        var units = (units)x.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes can be fixed by replacing use of [`[XmlArray]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute) and [`[XmlArrayItem]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute) with [`[XmlElement(typeof(TDerived))]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute):

```
public class UnitSerializer
{
    public abstract class item
    {
    }

    public class entity : item
    {
        [XmlElement("health", typeof(health))]
        [XmlElement("entity", typeof(entity))]
        [XmlElement("sprite", typeof(sprite))]
        public List<item> EntityList { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class component : item
    {
    }

    public class health : component
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int max { get; set; }
    }

    public class sprite : component
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string texture { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("units")]
    public class units
    {
        [XmlElement("health", typeof(health))]
        [XmlElement("entity", typeof(entity))]
        [XmlElement("sprite", typeof(sprite))]
        public List<item> EntityList { get; set; }
    }

    public units Read(string filename)
    {
        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(units));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs))
        {
            return (units)x.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- `[XmlArray]` indicates a collection should be serialized with an outer wrapper element containing a sequence of elements, while `[XmlElement]` indicates a collection should be serialized as a sequence without the wrapper.  Your XML sample uses repeating elements without wrapper elements, so `[XmlElement]` should be used.  It *sort of works* because your XML is recursive -- but at every other level repeating elements are getting incorrectly deserialized as wrappers.  This explains why some but not all data is lost during deserialization.
- In your XML sample, polymorphic elements are identified by element name.  The [`XmlSerializer(Type, Type[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Type___) constructor should be used to specify polymorphic included types to be serialized using the [`xsi:type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes#serializing-derived-classes) mechanism.  Since the [`xsi:type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ca1ks327(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) attribute does not appear in your XML, this constructor need not be used.

  (In addition, when constructing an `XmlSerializer` using the `XmlSerializer(Type, Type[])` constructor, you must cache the serializer statically to avoid a severe memory leak.  See *[Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182)* for why.)
- [`XmlTextReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=net-5.0) has been deprecated since .Net 2.0.  Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.
- The `FileStream` and `XmlReader` should be disposed, ideally via `using` statements.
- I eliminated the `public class componentlist : List<item>` and replaced it with just a `List<item>`.  This was mainly a matter of taste, but it does make it easier to set the value of such a list using Linq's [`.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x32HGE).

Comment: thank you for the excellent and exhausting answer! I also now could get rid of the duplicate EntityList property definition by ineriting units from entity .