# Huge string memory leak running a service

Tags: windows, wcf, service, memory-leaks, .net-4.7.2

We have an application that we run as a service. It uses WCF but I not sure that this is relevant.

After running the application under JetBrains .dotMemory there are nearly 10GB of objects (mainly strings) and I have no idea where they have come from. The retention path is not available.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
Ian

[image]

Comment: Are you using `XmlSerializer` and constructing your serializer with a constructor other than `new XmlSerializer(Type)` or `new XmlSerializer(Type, string)`?  If so, you may be hitting the problem from [Memory Leak using StreamReader and XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23897145/3744182).

Comment: XmlSerializer is not being used anywhere in the code so it cannot be anything to do with that

Comment: We are not using WPF at all either

Comment: I have corrected my post so say WCF rather than WPF. We are using .NET 4.7.2

Comment: The first few strings look like they may be related to Web.Config.  If you sort the strings by bytes, are there any that are unusually large?  Or if you sort by value, are there any whose values are duplicated many, many times?

Comment: Most of these strings are not even in the app.config file. The app.config file is quite basic and there are no duplicate entries.

Comment: They look like interned string literals from the .NET framework code that parses the config file.  Makes sense that they would appear at the beginning.

Comment: Is there any loop in the code? There may be an endless loop that causes this problem.

Comment: Objects retained directly by object[] most likely objects retained by static fields. I suspect that 1778 quite shorts strings could not take 10Gb of memory.
Scope to objects exclusively retained by this object[] instance (button on the left side panel item) and see what objects took so much memory.