# how to remove xml tags for a serialized xml string

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a simple method that is used C# .Net classes to serialize a list of objects to a XML string.  For that method, I'd like to remove xml elements from the produced XML string. Please help. Thank you.

My method:

```
  public static string CreateXML(List<Video> list)
        {
            string result = "";
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            s.Serialize(stringWriter, list);

            result = stringWriter.ToString();

            return result;
        }
```

The result string (I cut off for brevity) I get from that method:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
 <ArrayOfVideo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <Video>- 
         ....
     </Video>

     <Video>
       ....
     </Video>

  </ArrayOfVideo>
```

I would like to have a result xml string like: (tag is added `<Videos> and </Videos>`)

```
<Videos>
    <Video>- 
             ....
         </Video>

         <Video>
           ....
         </Video>
</Videos>
```

**So, I want to remove lines:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<ArrayOfVideo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</ArrayOfVideo>
```

Comment: See if this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624540/how-to-set-root-node-name-when-xmlserializing-an-array) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML to parse easily the document and create a new XElement with name "Videos" having the "Video" elements inside from the loaded and parsed document. This can be done in two lines with LINQ to XML.

```
XElement element1 = XElement.Load("Videos.xml");

XElement element2 = new XElement ("Videos", element1.Elements("Video"));
```

Comment: @Efstahios, thank for you answer. But my method needs to have List<Video> list collection to be passed in as argument instead reading an external xml file.

Comment: Possible duplicate question. Go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772004/how-can-i-make-the-xmlserializer-only-serialize-plain-xml